# How can I define a command that uses round parentheses around its arguments?

Tags: macros, parentheses

I defined a command for probability distributions, for example:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\RoundBrackets}[1]{(}{)}{#1}
\newcommand{\p}[1]{\RoundBrackets{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{|}{\mid}}}
```

This can be used as `\p{x|y}`. However, I would like to use it as `\p(x|y)`. Is there some TeX magic to make that possible?

Comment: Please state your question clearly and give a minimal working example!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) makes defining a macro with a different kind of mandatory argument delimiter requirement fairly easy. Below, `r()` does just that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,xparse,etoolbox}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\RoundBrackets}[1]{(}{)}{#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pr}{ r() }{%
  \def\prArg{#1}% Capture argument in macro
  \patchcmd{\prArg}{|}{\mid}{}{}% Replace | with \mid
  \RoundBrackets{\prArg}% Set argument in round brackets
}

\begin{document}

$\pr(a|b)$

\end{document}
```

[`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is used to replace `|` with `\mid`.

Comment: Great, thank you! This also works with mathematical symbols inside the probability distribution that I had problems with earlier. Is there any reason why defining my probability distributions like this would be discouraged?

Comment: How would I modify this to pass the symbol in front of the parentheses (`p`, `q` , `p_\theta`, etc) into the command? I know I can just write it before the command but it would be easier to see that it belongs together if it were an argument.

Comment: @danijar: Look at [this example](https://pastebin.com/jXS5dSUZ).

Answer (score 12):

This also supports the usual options for `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\p}{sO{}r()}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \mleft(
    \danijar_middlevert:
    #3
    \mright)
   }
   {
    \group_begin:
    \danijar_sizedvert:n {#2}
    \mathopen{#2(}
    #3
    \mathclose{#2)}
    \group_end:
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \danijar_middlevert:
 {
  \char_set_active_eq:NN | \__danijar_middle:
  \mathcode`|="8000 \scan_stop:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__danijar_middle:
 {
  \;\middle\vert\;
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \danijar_sizedvert:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__danijar_size_tl { #1 }
  \char_set_active_eq:NN | \__danijar_mid:
  \mathcode`|="8000 \scan_stop:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__danijar_mid:
 {
  \mathrel{\l__danijar_size_tl\vert}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\p(x) \neq \p(x|y)$
\qquad
$\p[\big](x) \neq \p[\big](x|y)$
\qquad
$\p[\Big](x) \neq \p[\Big](x|y)$
\qquad
$\p*(\dfrac{a}{b})\neq \p*(\dfrac{a}{b}|y)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to locally make `|` math active, with an appropriate definition, which is `\;\middle\vert\;` when automatic sizing is declared, or `\mathrel{<size>\vert}` when a manual size is selected.

If you want to add the “P” for “probability”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\p}{sO{}r()}
 {
  \operatorname{P}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \mleft(
    \danijar_middlevert:
    #3
    \mright)
   }
   {
    \group_begin:
    \danijar_sizedvert:n {#2}
    \mathopen{#2(}
    #3
    \mathclose{#2)}
    \group_end:
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \danijar_middlevert:
 {
  \char_set_active_eq:NN | \__danijar_middle:
  \mathcode`|="8000 \scan_stop:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__danijar_middle:
 {
  \;\middle\vert\;
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \danijar_sizedvert:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__danijar_size_tl { #1 }
  \char_set_active_eq:NN | \__danijar_mid:
  \mathcode`|="8000 \scan_stop:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__danijar_mid:
 {
  \mathrel{\l__danijar_size_tl\vert}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\p(x) \neq \p(x|y)$

$\p[\big](x) \neq \p[\big](x|y)$

$\p[\Big](x) \neq \p[\Big](x|y)$

$\p*(\dfrac{a}{b})\neq \p*(\dfrac{a}{b}|y)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. It's a bit more than what I need right now, but if I need symbols of vastly different height inside the parentheses I can go back here and replace the macro with this one.

Answer (score 10):

Probably [@Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446678/38080) is the way to go (robust and easily modified), but in this case, plain TeX also seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\pr(#1|#2){(#1 \mid #2)}

\begin{document}

$\pr(a|b)$
$\pr(a_r|b^2)$

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting output]

Comment: This makes the use of `|` also mandatory (for conditional probability), which might not be the case in general. You'll have to update the definition of `\pr` to accommodate for that conditional use.